# How to resolve unknown error on if, else statement in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I try to run the program, it would always show "Your answer is Wrong" regardless of the answer.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ICTPETA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    String name = input.nextLine();
    
    System.out.print("Date: ");
    String date = input.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println ("A. True or False");
    System.out.println ("Directions: Read each statement carefully. If the statement is correct, type True. Otherwise, type False");
    
    String answer1 = "";
    
    System.out.println ("1. Can an identifier have spaces?");
    answer1 = input.nextLine();
    
    if (false)
    {
        System.out.println("Your answer is Correct!");
    }
    
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Your answer is Wrong");
    }
    
    }

}
```

Comment: You have `if (false)` instead of something like `if (answer1.equals("..."))`.

Comment: `if` evaluates a boolean (true or false) expression. In your case `false` evaluates to... `false`, so it runs the `else`. You need to actually evaluate `answer1` in some form.